# Terminal: Randomize 4 letters from a list of letters. sort -R awk

Tags: sorting, awk, terminal

I'm using this code below to randomize 4 letters from a list of letters. I'm now trying to mod it without success.

`sort -R /Users/macbook/Desktop/letters.txt | awk 'NR <= 4 { print $1 }'`

1. Now the 4 letters is render in the terminal as a list/rows but it want them to be only in one row.
2. Instead of enter this code each time to get one letter combination, Is there a way to get 10 random letter combinations?

---

**EXAMPLE**

**Now I get this when enter the code above:**

a
d
r
e

**I want this to be like this:**

a d r e

t u i o

i o m d

e p j w

q o j b

d o e d

v d a k

l s u f

l o d s

p d v x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v n=4 -v letters="$(echo {a..z})" '
        BEGIN{srand(); 
              s=split(letters,le); 
              while(1) 
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                  printf "%s%s", le[int(rand()*s)+1], (i==n?ORS:OFS)}' | head

v o e i
k s l y
j u d d
b i q q
u r b d
s o f p
y x f j
k b g a
m y i s
z t d p
```

note that this creates an infinite stream of 4 char records and you can control the count with the `head` filter (by default 10 records).  You can provide number of chars in the `n` variable.

Also note that this corresponds to sampling with replacement, so you can get the same char multiple times even on the same row.  If you want no repeats in the same row, this needs to be tweaked.

This version will have unique chars in each row

```
$ awk -v n=4 -v letters="$(echo {a..z})" '
          BEGIN{srand(); 
                s=split(letters,le); 
                while(1) 
                  {do 
                     {r=int(rand()*s)+1; a[r]} 
                   while(length(a)<n); 
                   for(r in a) printf "%s ",le[r]; 
                   print ""; delete a}}' | head
g i q u
d n w y
l p u x
c g l s
a f q r
l p q v
a j t x
a g r x
h k n z
k r v z
```

for example use 2gram starting with a vowel

```
$ awk -v n=4 -v letters="$(echo {a,e,i,o,u}{a..z})" '...'

an ek is up
ir iu oy ug
ea is oc ur
ay ei en if
ab er iz up
eq er ev uf
ab ek in oz
eo ip ov ua
ek eq oz uz
ao ex ij io
```

Comment: thats really cool, need to look in to this more! But is there a way to take the letters from a list in case of we add letter combinations?

Comment: the input is in the variable `letters`, provide the letters in a space delimted string, like `a b c d...`

Comment: Yes, but if I want to have: **er yt wc bg…**

Comment: it treats each space separated char as a token, it can be two chars as well.  Please see the example

Comment: Thank you big time, it works perfect! I just can't figure out, after googling, how to change so I can add more rows. "head filter (by default 10 records)"

Also, while all rows be unique?

Comment: `head -10` is the default behavior, change 10 to the desired number of records.  Each record is independent draw so there is no guarantee that they will be unique.

Comment: Awesome, thanx @karakfa! Now it works like I want. I still need to learn some of the code though!